# Is there a live backend demo of drupal commerce?

Tags: commerce

Is there a live Drupal Commerce backend demo site?  I would like to take a look before trying to download and install it.

Comment: Try simplytest.me.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to https://simplytest.me
2. Fill in "commerce kickstart"
3. Select the latest version: 7.x-2.41
4. Click "Launch sandbox"
5. Follow the step-by-step on-screen instructions, including the database configuration screen. You will notice that all fields are already filled in so you can just press "Next".